# Formulaic Representation of k-Permutations

Tags: permutations, permutation-matrices

Out of a set $S = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, I am picking elements $1$ and $5$. I then want to create all [k=2-permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n) from the remaining elements. For instance:

$$
1 \rightarrow \mathbf{2} \rightarrow \mathbf{3} \rightarrow 5 \\
1 \rightarrow \mathbf{3} \rightarrow \mathbf{2} \rightarrow 5 \\
1 \rightarrow \mathbf{4} \rightarrow \mathbf{3} \rightarrow 5 \\
\dots
$$

In my notation, a permutation $1 \rightarrow \mathbf{2} \rightarrow \mathbf{3} \rightarrow 5$ correspons to the matrix elements $a_{21}a_{32}a_{53}$.

How can I describe the sum of the matrix elements corresponding to the permutations formulaically (along the lines of $\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}a_{ij}$)?

$$
a_{21}a_{32}a_{53} + a_{31}a_{23}a_{52} + a_{41}a_{34}a_{53} + \dots \ (\text{all permutations)} =  \sum_ ?
$$

Comment: This is hard to follow and you are using some of your words incorrectly.  In the end, the summation you seem to be after might as well be described with words since describing it with notation can be unnecessarily difficult to read.  It is unclear why you want this summation in the first place or what it would be useful for.

Comment: If I were forced to write with notation, I would have written: $\sum\limits_{(x,y)\in \{2,3,4\}^2\\x\neq  y}a_{x,1}a_{y,x}a_{5,y}$

Comment: How about $\sum_{n,m=1}^{5}a_{n1}a_{mn}a_{5m}\delta_{m5}\delta_{m1}\delta_{n1}\delta_{n5}\delta_{nm}$, where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta?

Comment: I'll gladly update the terminology if you point out where I can improve it.

Comment: ...ah, $\delta$ won't work - I used that just the wrong way around.

Comment: ...so perhaps: $\sum_{n,m=1}^{5} a_{n1}a_{mn}a_{m5} \times (1-\delta_{m5})(1-\delta_{m1}) \dots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific permutation, I found the following representation sufficient:

$$
\sum_{n,m=1}^{5}a_{n1}a_{mn}a_{m5} \times (1-\delta_{mn})(1-\delta_{m1})(1-\delta_{m5})(1-\delta_{n1})(1-\delta_{n5})
$$

where $\delta$ is [the Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).